# Audio conference between WPF Applications

Tags: wpf, audio, naudio

I have 2 WPF applications that communicate using a couple of duplex WCF services. I need to   enable audio communication also between them. I've been looking for a solution for a while now, but couldn't find a good one.

What I've tried is audio streaming using Microsoft Expression Encoder on the "server" side (the one that feeds the audio), and playing it on the "client" using VLC .NET. It works, at least streaming a song, but it's a big resource eater. The initial buffering also takes a lot, and so is stopping the stream.

What other options do I have? I want a clear, lightweight audio conversation between the apps, kinda like Skype. Is this possible? Thanks

**EDIT**: I found NAudio and it looks like a good audio library, I managed to stream my microphone quite easily. However, I have big problem - I can hear the voice clearly on the client, but it echoes indefinitely. Plus, there's this annoying background sound (could this be caused by the processor?) and after a while, a very high, loud sound is played on the receiving end. All I can do is stop the whole transmission. I have no idea what's causing these problems. I use the 'SpeexChatCodec' as in the NetworkChat example provided (sampling rate: 8000, 2 channels). Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot of work to write a library that would support that from scratch... if you can spend $150 on this I would suggest purchasing a library like [iConf .NET Video Conferencing SDK](http://www.avspeed.com/avcontent/iconf-net-video-conferencing-sdk) from [AvSpeed](http://www.avspeed.com/)...

Comment: I can't, it's an application for my bachelor thesis. Other options? Can't the sound from the mic be sent over the network as a byte array?